# limit a network interface to connect to a single target IP

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I am setting a Windows tablet which has multiple network interface including very low bandwidth that should be used by our specific program.

How could I limit the NIC interface possible target IP.
I don't want normal internet traffic to go over it, only connection to a specific IP address / server.

Comment: How does your program connect to the Internet?  With sockets? Or with an http cilent call?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called ***routing***. If you can set the routing table as root (resp. administrator), you can do what you describe. Just set a default gateway over the "big" interface and set one dedicated route via your "narrow" gateway interface.